# Algorithm | Solving O(N^2) complexity to something lesser?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following data:

```
P1:
    H1, H2, H3
P2:
    H1, H4
P3:
    H1,H4
```

The output should be:

```
H1: [P1, P2], [P1, P3], [P2, P3]
H2: [P1]
H3: [P1]
H4: [P2, P3]
```

The output is based on every 'P's that intersects with every 'H'.
Ex: H1 is common between P1, P2 and P3.

I've solved it as an N^2 problem where N is number of P's. Any room for optimisation? Can I reduce the complexity to linear space somehow?

The number of P's can go upto 2000. Number of H's within each P can go upto 15.

I have my (Pseudo-code) something like this:

```
for(p1 in P) {
  h1 = listOfH(p1);
    for(p2 in P) {
      h2 = listOfH(p2);
      intersections = findIntersectingHs(h1, h2);
      record(intersections, p1, p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all we need your solution

Answer (score 2):

It can't be faster than O(n^2) because with input.

```
P1: H1  
P2: H1  
P3: H1  
....  
P_N: H1
```

the output is every pair `H1: [P_i, P_j]` where  `i < j` which are `O(n^2)`. However if you needed only something like `H1: [P1, P2, P3] H2: [P1] H3: [P1] H4: [P2, P3]` as an answer to your example i think it can be fastened.